# How can I plot the 2D line of a section taken across a contour plot, along the line y=x, in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

So if I've plotted a contour plot of a 3D function, is there a way I can take a cross section of this, and plot it as a conventional 2D plot, using the contour function?

Comment: You may be able to use interp2 for this. Look at the following post on MatlabCentral [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13152-how-to-plot-a-cross-section-of-a-surface-plot)

Comment: @MZimmerman6 As it seems the asker is already able to make the contour plot at maximum dimensions, I don't think he is looking for a way to fill missing points.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin maybe, the 1 sentence question was fairly nondescript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data comes from a two dimensional grid called `grid` it easy to take a cross section of this:

```
v = grid(myRow,:);
```

or

```
v = grid(:, myCol);
```

or

```
v = diag(grid);
```

**Example**:

```
grid = magic(12);
contour(grid);
myRow = 4;
v = diag(grid);
figure,plot(v)
```

Comment: Note the OP says "along the line y=x". So the cross-section would be, assuming `grid` is square: `v = grid(sub2ind(size(grid),1:length(grid),1:length(grid)))`. Or better `grid(1:length(grid)+1:length(grid)^2)`

Comment: @LuisMendo Good point, I have incldued `diag` in the example.